# While running the test in Rubymine, It takes long time to download the file from server

Tags: rubymine

When i tried running my test cases in rubymine it is taking long time and when i force stop it, asking for password. I m not sure what is root cause, because when i run it in local/dev before it was working but now it is not working.

Any suggestions would really help and Thanks for your time

Testing started at 2:23 PM ...
Running in Environment: test
Using temp directory: temp/0f9fbd55b6eae33875fdd42ef51ee106
Downloading /home/username/.priv/.td_connection to temp/0f9fbd55b6eae33875fdd42ef51ee106/.td_connection

Process finished with exit code -1
username@server's password:

Comment: Are your files on the local storage? If not have you tried synchronizing them with a local copy of the project?

Comment: Thanks Olivia, I got the solution, it was because of the SSH issue. Thanks for your time. :)